# Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte

Tags: c#

Getting the following error :

> System.OverflowException has been thrown - Value was either too large
>   or too small for an unsigned byte.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            int decValue = 2210;
            string bin = Convert.ToString(decValue, 2);
            string lowerbyte = bin.Substring(Math.Max(0, bin.Length - 16));

            if (lowerbyte.Length < 16)
            {
                lowerbyte = lowerbyte.PadLeft(16, '0');
            }


        Int16 circular = Convert.ToByte(CicrularLeftShift(lowerbyte, 3), 2);

            string xored = Convert.ToString((circular ^ 38556), 2).Substring(Math.Max(0, Convert.ToString((circular ^ 38556), 2).Length - 16));

            //converting final binary shift value to HEX
            string finalHex = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(xored, 2), 16).ToUpper();

        Console.WriteLine(finalHex);

    }

    private static string CicrularLeftShift(string key, int shift)
    {
        return key.Substring(shift, key.Length - shift) + key.Substring(0, shift);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to happen when the input is out of range for an unsigned byte? it's also a bit strange you're assigning the result of `Convert.ToByte` to an `Int16` - do you want to convert to a `short` instead?

Comment: Not clear what you want to get, but I doubt you need to convert numbers to string and back to number and back to string to do it.
what is your expected result?

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: What's the value that you're trying to convert?

Comment: I'm trying to convert input value to BIN and than extract two lowest bytes from that value, than I have to perform three consecutive circular shift to left and XOR that value with 38556, and finally that value convert to HEX. It works fine for numbers up to 30, anything above 30 gives me an error.

Comment: The value when it breaks is `"0100010100010000"` (that's the return value from `CircularLeftShift`) - so: what do you want to do with that? You're trying to convert 15 bits (from the first non-zero) to a byte (8 bits). Did you mean `Convert.ToInt16`?

Comment: as a side note: doing binary via string ops makes me shudder to the core...

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to Convert.ToByte.

A Byte is 8 bits. You are supplying a 16 bit number in your string.

Change your references to 16, to 8 if you want a single Byte. Or if you do want Int16 then use Convert.ToInt16.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wxkt09k(v=vs.110).aspx